# Replacing folder in publishing profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, publishing, webdeploy

I have a MVC project with VS Publishing profiles to publish it. This works fine, but in my web.config I have a parameter which points to a certain file on disk. It has to be a full path, otherwise the code (external code) does not work / find the file.

So I'd like to include somekind of $installdir variable in the publishing profile or web.config to make sure it gets replaced by the actual installation folder upon deployment. I searched for a way to do this, but couldn't find it. Anyone know whether this can bee done?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change web.config file during deploy I'd suggest using [web.config transformation syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, if you deploy using a release build configuration, update Web.Release.config like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="MyFilePath" value="C:\Prod\Folder\file.txt" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>;
<configuration>
```